# Input reset and submit doesnt work

Tags: php, forms, html

this is my form, my input reset don't reset all my input and submit don't send my form,
when I press input reset it doesn't work and dont know why and the same happening with submit 
what should i do??

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Agregar Publicidad</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/EstiloLocales.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../libs/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"/>
<script src="../libs/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="../libs/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.checkin').click(function(){
                var labelId = $(this).attr('name');
                var colorActual = $('#'+labelId).css('color');
                var checkeo = $(this).attr('checked');
                $('#COLOSH').val(checkeo);
                if(checkeo == 'checked'){
                    $('#'+labelId).css('color','#f00');
                    }else{
                        $('#'+labelId).css('color','#000');
                        }
                var n = $("input:checkbox").length;
                var str = '';       
                for(var cj=1; cj < n; cj++){
                    var check = document.getElementById(cj+'1').checked; 
                    if(check == true){
                        str += cj+' ';
                        }
                    }
                $('#myArr').val(str);
            });  

        });

    function cargarCategorias(cadena){
            var ar= cadena.split(" ");
            if(ar.length < 3){
                $('#'+ar+'1').prop("checked", true);
                $('#label'+ar).css("color", "#f00");
            }else{
                ar = ar.split(' ');
                for(var i=0;i < ar.length; i++){
                    $('#'+ar[i]+'1').prop("checked", true);
                    $('#label'+ar[i]).css("color", "#f00");
                }
            }

        }   
    function porDefecto(){
            $('.label').css('color','#000');
            //$(':input').attr('value','');
            //$('#descripcion').attr('value','');
        }

       function loaddefimages(Id)  
        {  
        //this.src='../Info/Fotos/fotogenerica.jpg
            document.getElementById(Id).src="../Info/Fotos/fotogenerica.jpg";  
        } 

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php 
    include "../src/defines.php";
    $numero = $_GET['numero'];
    $doc = new DOMDocument; 
    $doc->load(DIR_LOCALES);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query('//item[@numero="'.$numero.'"]');
    //if ($elements->length >= 1) {
        $element = $elements->item(0);
    $ar = buscar_categorias( $element->getAttribute('nombre'),DIR_PUBLICIDADES);
        if($ar != ''){
            $t= implode(' ',$ar);
            ?>
            <script language="javascript">
                var cadena = <?php echo $t;?>
                cargarCategorias(cadena);
            </script>
            <?php

            } 
    //  }                               
    ?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="add_local.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="myArr" name="myArr" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="oldvalue" name="oldvalue" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="accion" name="accion" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="oldName" name="oldName" value="">
<div class="div_principal">
    <div class="contenido">
        <div class="contenido-uno">
          <div class="datos"><!--BEGIN DATOS -->
                <div class="datos-uno"><!--BEGIN DATOS UNO -->
                     <div>
                         <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                         <input name="nombre"  type="text" id="nombre" maxlength="21" style="margin-left:15px;" value="<?php if($element->getAttribute('nombre') == ''){ echo "NO ASIGNADO";}else{echo $element->getAttribute('nombre');} ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                         <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                          <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono"  style="margin-left:10px;" value="<?php if($element->getAttribute('telefono') == ''){ echo "NO ASIGNADO";}else{echo $element->getAttribute('telefono');} ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="web">Web</label>
                      <input type="text" name="web" id="web" value="<?php if($element->getAttribute('web') == ''){ echo "NO ASIGNADO";}else{echo $element->getAttribute('web');} ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
                      <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo"  value="<?php if($element->getAttribute('correo') == ''){ echo "NO ASIGNADO";}else{echo $element->getAttribute('correo');} ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="encargado">Encargado</label>
                        <input type="text" name="encargado" id="encargado"  value="<?php if($element->getAttribute('encargado') == ''){ echo "NO ASIGNADO";}else{echo $element->getAttribute('encargado');} ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div><!--END DATOS UNO -->
                <div class="datos-dos"><!--BEGIN DATOS DOS -->
                    <div>
                        <label for="numero">Número</label>
                        <input type="text" disabled="disabled"  style="margin-left:30px;" name="numero" id="numero" value="<?php echo $element->getAttribute('numero') ?>"  />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                          <label for="descripcion"> Descripción</label>
                        </div>
                        <div style=" position:relative; top:-20px; left:100px;">
                          <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" style="width:240px; height:100px;"    ><?php if($element->getAttribute('descripcion') == ''){ echo "NO ASIGNADO";}else{echo $element->getAttribute('descripcion');} ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                        <label for="promocion">Promoción</label>
                        <input type="text" name="promocion" id="promocion" value="<?php if($element->getAttribute('promocion') == ''){ echo "NO ASIGNADO";}else{echo $element->getAttribute('promocion');} ?>" style="margin-left:15px;" />
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- FIN DATOS -->

      <div class="imagenes"><!-- BEGIN IMAGENES -->
            <div class="ima-uno">
                <div class="div-foto">
                    <img id="foto" onerror="javascript:loaddefimages(this.id);" src="../Info/Fotos/Localimg/<?php echo strtolower($element->getAttribute('numero').'jpg'); ?>" alt="Foto" name="foto" width="310" height="115"  />Imagen  297 x 110 px
                </div>
                <div class="div-btn">
                    <img src="../src/Img/paneldecontrol-15.png" width="23" height="23" style="position:absolute;" />
                  <input style="width:67px; z-index:2; opacity:0;" type="file" name="dir_foto"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ima-dos">
          <div class="div-logo">
            <img id="logo" src="../Info/Fotos/logos/<?php echo strtolower($element->getAttribute('numero').'png'); ?>" onerror="javascript:loaddefimages(this.id);" alt="logo" width="150" height="115" /></div>
          <div class="div-btn-logo">
          <img src="../src/Img/paneldecontrol-15.png" width="23" height="23" style="position:absolute;" />
           <input  style="width:67px;  z-index:2; opacity:0;"  type="file" name="dir_logo" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="contenido-dos">
            <div class="div_cat">     
                 <?php
                 $docCat = new DomDocument;
                 $docCat->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
                 $docCat->load(DIR_CATEGORIAS);
                 $parCat = $docCat->getElementsByTagName('categoria'); // Find Sections
                 $contador=0;
                 foreach($parCat as $parametro){
                 ?> 
                 <div>
                    <input id="<?php  echo $parCat->item($contador)->getAttribute('id'); ?>1"  class="checkin"  type="checkbox" name="label<?php  echo $parCat->item($contador)->getAttribute('id'); ?>" />         
                    <label id="label<?php  echo $parCat->item($contador)->getAttribute('id'); ?>" class="label"  for="a"><?php  echo $parCat->item($contador)->getAttribute('nombre'); ?></label>           
                 </div>
                  <?php 
                 $contador++;
                  }
                 ?>
           </div>
           <div class="form-buttons">
                <img src="../src/Img/paneldecontrol-17.png" width="23" height="23" style="position:absolute; left: 2px; top: 1px;" />
                <input type="reset" onclick="javascript:porDefecto();"  style=" z-index:2; width:25px; margin-right:7px; height:23px; opacity:0; " value="Limpiar" />Limpiar campos
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:7px; width:27px; height:23px; z-index:3; opacity:0; " />Guardar
                <img src="../src/Img/paneldecontrol-16.png" width="23" height="23" style="position:absolute; left: 152px; top: 1px;"  /> 
            </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

div form-buttons has the input that doesn't work

Comment: For some reason there are too many nested divs in my eyes.

Comment: Any scripts on your page that might be catching clicks or stopping submission?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'reset' has an 'onclick' event, which is wrong. I bet that prevents the reset..

Some of the input elements are disabled, and I doubt wether disabled elements are posted.

For the generated elements, I think it's best to load your page and check the output (the generated source). I will tell you more easily if there's any error in the PHP code, than staring at the PHP source.